# PAssert...containsInAnyOrder fails despite the proper result

Tags: unit-testing, apache-beam

I have following code:

```
PAssert.that(output)
            .inWindow(GlobalWindow.INSTANCE)
            .containsInAnyOrder(buildObjectTypeT()...build()
```

output is produced by

```
PCollection<T> someMethod
```

PAssert fail with

```
Expected: iterable over [<T(id=..
but: Not matched: <T(id=2
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that containsInAnyOrder fails if output contains more than the list of objects that is expected.

Lets say `PCollection<T> someMethod` produces 3 elements . If `containsInAnyOrder(T obj1, T obj2)` then PAssert will fail

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the expected is an `iterable` but given a `<T...>`.
Try enclosing the expected object in an array.

Comment: see my answer below - reason was different